# How to make time buckets with a start and end time column?

Tags: mysql, sql, time, grouping, bucket

I have 3 columns, employee_id, start_time and end_time I want to make bucks of 1 hour to show me how many employees were working in each hour. For example, employee A worked from 12 pm to 3 pm and employee B worked from 2 pm to 4 pm so, at 12 pm (1 employee was working) 1 pm (1 employee) 2 pm (2 employees were working) 3 pm (2 employees) and 4 pm (1 employee), how can I make this in SQL? Let me show you a picture of the start and end time columns.

Sample input would be:

[image: this]

Expected outcome would be something like

[image: this]

I want to create a bucket in order to know how many people were working in each hour of the day.

SELECT

```
  Employee_id,
  TIME(shift_start_at,timezone) AS shift_start,
  TIME(shift_end_at,timezone) AS shift_end,
  
FROM
  `employee_shifts` AS shifts
 
WHERE
  DATE(shifts.shift_start_at_local) >= "2022-05-01"
  
GROUP BY
  1,
  2,
  3
```

Comment: Please provide sample input, expected outcome and the entire table structure as tables.

Comment: Images/links aren't useful particularly incomplete ones missing headers Text is better. And how to you arrive at the second column in your desired outcome which unexpectedly (for me) contains decimal places when your question asks 'how many people were working in each hour'?-

Comment: If the shift ends at 1:15pm that count like the employee worked in the bucket of 1pm (1:00pm to 1:59pm).

Comment: You are missing to show the entire table structure, you are missing to provide input and outcome as tables (as asked for), you keep just uploading any screenshots that don't really help to answer your question. How do you expect that people will give good answers when you refuse to put sufficient effort to ask your question in a good way? Don't let other people do all the work you could do.

Comment: Sorry, i am new at this, if you could explain how can i show you what you are asking for? I trying to learn!!

Comment: This is difficult in comments, but there are very many articles about this that can be found using google, as example this one which shows how to create tables: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220127/how-to-make-tables-in-good-format-in-asking-questions-here-which-is-understanda

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are on mysql version 8 or above generate all the buckets , left join to shifts to infill times in start-endtime ranges , filter out those that are not applicable then count eg:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t;

create table t (id int, startts datetime, endts datetime);

insert into t values
(1,'2022-06-19 08:30:00','2022-06-19 10:00:00'),
(2,'2022-06-19 08:30:00','2022-06-19 08:45:00'),
(3,'2022-06-19 07:00:00','2022-06-19 07:59:00');

 with cte as 
(select 7 as bucket union select 8 union select 9 union select 10 union select 11),
cte1 as
(select bucket,t.*,
             floor(hour(startts)) starthour, floor(hour(endts)) endhour
from cte
left join t on cte.bucket between floor(hour(startts)) and floor(hour(endts)) 
) 
select bucket,count(id) nof from cte1 group by bucket
;
+--------+-----+
| bucket | nof |
+--------+-----+
|      7 |   1 |
|      8 |   2 |
|      9 |   1 |
|     10 |   1 |
|     11 |   0 |
+--------+-----+
5 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Comment: `CROSS JOIN` with a `WHERE` clause is just an `INNER JOIN`. That also means you're going to lose buckets with no shifts, so I'd recommend `bucket LEFT JOIN shift` with `COUNT(shift.employee_id)` instead.

Comment: You ***need*** to change the COUNT too. Else buckets with no shifts will return a count of 1.

Answer (score 1):

If you have ***a limited number of time bucket*** maybe you can use it this way

```
WITH CTE AS
    (SELECT 
         COUNTRY,
         MONTH,
         TIMESTAMP_DIFF(time_b, time_a, MINUTE) dt,
         METRIC_a,
         METRIC_b
     FROM
         TABLE_NAME)
SELECT
      CASE 
          WHEN dt BETWEEN 0 AND 10 THEN "0-10"
          WHEN dt BETWEEN 10 AND 20 THEN "11-20"
          WHEN dt BETWEEN 20 AND 30 THEN "21-30"
          WHEN dt BETWEEN 30 AND 40 THEN "31-40"
          WHEN dt > 40 THEN ">40"
      END as time_bucket,
      AVG(METRIC_a),
      SUM(METRIC_b)
FROM CTE
```

Althought, I should emphasize that this solution works if you have a **limited bucket**. If you have a lot of buckets, you can create a base table with your buckets then `LEFT JOIN` it to get your results.

Comment: I think there should be a way to use recursive queries to do this too. Cause you want to go through a time bucket series which is gonna end and you can subtract a fixed period of time from your base time to create the buckets.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a subquery for each column mentioning the required timestamp in between, also make sure your start_time and end_time columns are timestamp types. For more information, please share the table structure, sample data, and expected output

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, this would be

```
SELECT HOUR, (SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM employee
 WHERE start_time <= HOUR
   AND end_time   >= HOUR) AS  working
  FROM schedule HOUR
```

Where schedule is a table with employee schedules.